# Does Mongoose auto cast types?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

When I retrieve and modify a Lobby with this Schema it seems to automatically cast types. I could not find the documentation for that feature so I am wondering if I am mistaken something else for autocasting.

I convert the types of password and owner to `true` or `false` because this is an exposed API endpoint everyone can view.

When I run the anonymizer function it runs and results in `password : "true"` not `password: true`. I would like it to send `password: true` but I am not sure if that is possible.

```js
// Schema
const LobbySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  password: String,
  owner: { type: String, require: true },
  Player: [],
});

// Anonymizer function
lobby.password = !!lobby.password;
lobby.owner = lobby.owner === user ? true: false;

res.send(JSON.stringify(lobby));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Mongoose cast values if it is possible.

The problem here is your schema define type `owner` as `String`. So the value `true` or `false` will be casted to string.

This is why you get `password : "true"`.

To get password as a boolean you can either set `Boolean` into the schema or use [Custom casting](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/custom-casting.html)

Not tested but following the documentation should be similar to this:

```js
const originalCast = mongoose.Boolean.cast();
mongoose.Boolean.cast(v => {
  if (v === 'true') {
    return true;
  }
  if (v === 'false') {
    return false;
  }
  return originalCast(v);
});
```